# How to add FB's page plugin to an AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-page

I want to use [Facebook's Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) to display posts from a Facebook Page in an AngularJS app. I know this can be done (prettier, better, smarter) through [the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed), but I'd rather just do the plugin if I can.

The plugin provides to pieces of code, the JS:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=271678779576853";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

I'd rather not hardcode the `script` tag in my Angular-templates, so when do I get it and fire it when I need it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you taken a look into [Angular-EasyFB](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb)?

Comment: @Buzinas: I glanced quickly over it, but missed the part about the [Social Plugins](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb#social-plugins-support). This looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: @Buzinas, if you want to post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. In the mean time, I've posted one detailing how to solve it using **EasyFB**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, [@Buzinas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832299/how-to-add-fbs-page-plugin-to-an-angularjs-application#comment53500576_32832299) was right. Just use the [Angular-EasyFB](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb) plugin. I just include the **Angular-EasyFB** module and follow the guide on [Social Plugins](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb#social-plugins-support).

I configure **Angular-EasyFB** module in my app's config block:

```
angular.module('app').config(function(ezfbProvider) {
    // Set up FB
    ezfbProvider.setLocale('da_DK');
    ezfbProvider.setInitParams({
        appId: 00000 // My FB APP ID
    });
});
```

The way to render a Facebook Page Plugin is by using the same code as the [generator creates for you](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin):

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-small-header="false" data-width="1000" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"></div>
```

And then it just *works*! Be aware, though, that the [RWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) capabilities of the Page Plugin is very limited.